# Clasic emoji unicode list

Tags: javascript, unicode, fonts, char, emoji

Good friends,

I am trying to send emojis through an API and I have noticed that it only accepts the most common emojis like ☹️☝️ and newer ones like  are shown as "????". From what I see only old emojis like ☹️ are the ones he accepts. These emojis are rendered as a font and have no color (just outline), the question is how do I get a list of these classic emojis? since it is difficult to separate those that are rendered as a font (without color, outlined) to new ones (with color).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your API only supports Unicode BMP (Basic Multilingual Plane) code points from U+0000 to U+FFFF, so you could filter by code point.  The ones that work are:

```
☹ U+2639 WHITE FROWNING FACE
☝ U+261D WHITE UP POINTING INDEX
```

And the ones that don't are:

```
 U+1F612 UNAMUSED FACE
 U+1F61D FACE WITH STUCK-OUT TONGUE AND TIGHTLY-CLOSED EYES
 U+1F924 DROOLING FACE
```

Refer to https://www.unicode.org/emoji/charts/index.html for a complete list of emoji.